# Can you use Ubuntu installation CD instead of Windows on Windows Automatic Recover?

Tags: system-installation, windows

My PC has been thrown into an Automatic Recovery loop, and nothing is working. The only option I have is to repair using a media disc, but I do not have one for Windows. If I select this option and use a disc that has Ubunutu on it, will it download properly/fix the problem/functionally run Ubuntu?

Comment: IMO, it's not possible to repair your windows boot files via Ubuntu live disk.

Comment: Why do you say that?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot repair a Windows boot issue with Ubuntu, because Ubuntu uses Grub2 and Windows uses it's own. Depending on the issue a Windows disc may not even be able to fix it. You will need a Windows installation disc that matches your Windows version (eg Windows 7 - Home Premium X86-64), or you will need to build a WinPE disc (which requires a functioning Windows installation to build on or maybe you could use wine?, and the version you want to build will depend on which version of Windows you are running). Long story short, you're pretty hooped. Sorry.

If you are desperate you could try building WinPE using wine (unlikely to work), but this tool is orientated towards experienced users, and even if the disc builds there no guarantee it can help you because it depends on the issue. WinPE cannot fix file issues, but it can fix bootloader issues. Bare minimum you can use WinPE to re-add the bootloader and create an entry for you Windows recovery partition. If you have Windows 8 then you will need to download WADK and build with it. If you have Windows 7 you will need WAIK instead. WinPE can only be used to install the Windows bootloader or add a boot entry. If you are having any other kind of a problem then an installation disc is needed. Re-installing the Windows bootloader will ovewrite grub on mbr systems and prevent you from booting Ubuntu. You need know if you have an MBR partition table or a GPT one.

Build A WinPE 3.0 Disc Using WAIK:

Download = http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=5753

Build Instructions = http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709665%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Build A WinPE 4.0 Disc Using WADK:

Download = http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30652

Build Instructions = http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/495354/how-to-create-a-winpe-40-disc-using-wadk-for-windows-8/

Answer (score 1):

if you use ubuntu live cd, you can either recover ubuntu or install ubuntu. if you only want to recover windows but not install ubuntu, i would suggest that before you try windows recovery media, download ubuntu and live boot it. you can access your windows hard drives. connect an external hard drive and backup all the important files. then experiment.